# Energy with mass correlation

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, speed-of-light, mass-energy, estimation

If the watch is working/ticking, its moving parts (gear, hand) contributes to extra mass where if we add potential, kinetic, and thermal energy and divide it by $c^2$, we get extra mass (small, but still) that the moving parts of the watch contribute to.

If the watch is broken/stopped and we weight it (2kg), what energy gets divided by $c^2$ to get 2kg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest energy of the clock is still the inherent energy of the matter, thermal energy, other internal energy of the clock regardless, to make 2 kg.

Also, the kinetic energy of the hands moving does not add to the rest mass because it is being pulled from the potential energy of a spring or a battery inside.  The motion is not added energy, it is the same energy in another form.

A good picture to remember is that if you take the clock and put it in a black box, and the black box shows a (net) weight gain of 2 kg, then that 2 kg is the rest mass – i.e. (rest energy)$/c^2$ – of everything inside. It doesn't matter if the clock is ticking, stops or spontaneously decays into radiation (as long as the box is impermeable). The mass inside the box and thus the rest energy remains the same in all of these cases.

Comment: Thank you, but we know that $ m = m_{component-or-rest} + m_{extra}$ where $m_{extra} = \frac{E_{PE+KE+Thermal}}{c^2} $. If the clock is not ticking, $m_{extra} = 0$. In your example, why does it show the same mass even if clock is ticking ? $m_{extra}$ must be > 0, hence m should be different for ticking clock

Comment: Because the increased kinetic energy of the ticking is exactly balanced by a decrease in potential energy of the spring that is causing it to tick (or decrease in the chemical energy if the battery is it is a modern clock)

Comment: I get that, but what I'm comparing is the watch that doesn't tick to the watch that ticks. The watch that doesn't tick doesn't have PE and KE, while the watch that ticks has PE + KE. So it should have bigger mass by $_{}=\frac{+}{c^2}$. Why not ?

Comment: Do you mean that even if the watch doesn't tick, it already has PE in the spring and then it's the total extra energy that gets converted to KE+thermal, overaly not changing this extra energy ? I get it, but i was referring to the case where the spring in the watch(which doesn't tick) is loose(no tighening) so PE = 0.

Comment: If you allow the clock to completely wind down and $then$ put it in the box, then yes it will have slightly less mass than when the spring was wound or when the hands were moving. If you ever want to know the rest mass, just use $m=E/c^2$. It is that simple

Comment: So by "rest energy", we mean inherent energy of the object ? in our case, the PE that clock's spring has is not included in rest energy ?

Comment: Yes it does mean inherent energy of the object, and yes the spring PE *is* included.  A clock with a wound up spring will have more mass than a clock with a relaxed spring (very slight of course in practice).

Comment: What I got confused with is your example where you said: "The mass inside the box and thus the rest energy remains the same in all of these cases.". I think this is not fully correct. If the clock's battery drains, the rest mass will not be the same as it was when battery of the clock was charged. I understand that it's not about ticking, but if battery drains or spring relaxes, rest energy decreases, which means rest mass decreases - hence not the same in all cases. This is the only thing left and I'm good

Comment: Well you have to be careful.  Say the clock is ticking and is sealed in the box.  When the spring winds down to a relaxed state, the hands will either continue spinning (if the clock is frictionless), or more likely the friction or mechanism in the clock will cause the clock to absorb that energy and heat up slightly. Ot it may radiate the energy to the rest of the box interior.  As long as the box is totally insulating the mass inside the box *will not change*.  The box does not care what form the energy inside it takes. The mass simply adds up all the energy inside in all forms.

Answer (score 0):

The watch stopped, because a bug crawled between gears. Some chemical bonds in the bug became broken. So bug has more energy. (Bug had always been living inside the watch)

If the above is not how the clock stopped, then you need to tell how it really happened.

Also information about what energy makes the clock tick may, or may not, be important.

Comment: The idea that I was making is imagine you got a watch(that doesn't tick as whoever created it didn't "turn it on") and you got a same watch that ticks. The answer @RC_23 gave me seems solid, but then what I don't understand is the reply I left to its answer.

Comment: @ZazaOrji When gears gained mass, battery lost mass. Mass moved from battery to motor through wires ... and so on....  If we are talking about battery clock being turned on.